# Running DataJpaTest for spring-boot application using TenantIdentifierResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-test

I have a spring boot app set up using [`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate-CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver) to manage tenantId's. I would like to test the repository layer of this application using `@DataJpaTest`. My test setup looks like:

```
@DataJpaTest(
    includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = TenantIdentifierResolver.class)
)
public class VendorRepositoryTest implements BaseTest {

  @Autowired
  private VendorRepository vendorRepository;

  @Test
  public void testVendorRepository() {
    TenantIdentifierResolver.forceTenantId("123", () -> {
      vendorRepository.save(new Vendor()
          .setName("name1");
    });

    TenantIdentifierResolver.forceTenantId("456", () -> {
      vendorRepository.save(new Vendor()
          .setName("name2"));

      Page<Vendor> a = vendorRepository.findAll(Pageable.ofSize(10));
      System.out.println(a);
    });
  }
}
```

This test creates two Vendors with different `@TenantId`'s. Repositories are aware of and respect the `TenantId` set in the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`.

However in this test scenario, the VendorRepository does not respect the TenantId, and returns both Vendors. I know that the `TenantIdentifierResolver` is being instantiated as part of the test run via breakpoints, but it is not being called by the repository to provide the tenantId's during the save. The db rows have empty tenantIds.

If I switch the `@DataJpaTest` for a `@SpringBootTest`, everything works properly and the tenantId's are respected.

Is there any way I can get the correct behavior with `@DataJpaTest` and avoid resorting to loading the full application context by switching to `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: Hi Kevin - Curious whether you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. It seems like a large oversight to me

Comment: Thanks for confirming,  I'll let you know if I find an answer elsewhere